# NodeJS with SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, linux, express, containers

1. How to run `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` SQL statement in NodeJS?
2. Please beware that the said SQL statement will return an empty header with a single record (hostname).
3. How to process and take that record and display it on express site ( or put it into some variable and call it in `.ejs` page

I manage to use `os.hostname`, but that will only give the NodeJS machine name, not the machine name where SSQL Server is running.

This is for demonstration of container/Kubernetes, so, If the web page returns the info of where the NodeJS and Server SQL is running, it will helpful.

Thank You again.

Update: What I've done so far:

```
const mssql = require('mssql');
const dbconfig = require('./src/config/dbconfig.json');
const pool = new mssql.ConnectionPool(dbconfig);
mssql.globalConnectionPool = pool;
//open database connection
pool.connect((err)=>{
  if (err){
    console.log('connection failed to server:' + dbconfig.server + ' database:' + dbconfig.database);
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
    console.log ('Connected to ' + dbconfig.server 
                    + '/' + dbconfig.database 
                    + ' (' + dbconfig.user + ')');
    const request = new mssql.Request(pool);
    request.query('select @@SERVERNAME',(err,rec)=>{
      console.log('SQL RUNNING AT ' +JSON.stringify(rec.recordset, null, 0)
        .replace('[{"":"', '')
        .replace('"}]','')
      );
    });
  }    
});
```

The above code returns the @@SERVERNAME value, but only prints out at console.log. How do I put this into a variable? and send to ejs?

Comment: Hi, I've done this, but this just displays the hostname on log, how to store that value in a variable so I can pass to my .ejs as variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing your query in SQL, such as from SSMS, you would give your result a column name, e.g.:

```sql
select [MyServerName] = @@SERVERNAME
```

```
MyServerName
--------------------
FOO\MSSQLSERVER
```

Or:

```sql
select @@SERVERNAME as MyServerName
```

```
MyServerName
--------------------
FOO\MSSQLSERVER
```

Do the same when invoking from NodeJS:

```js
    request.query('select @@SERVERNAME as MyServerName',(err, result)=>{
      const myServerName = result.recordset[0].MyServerName;
      console.log('SQL RUNNING AT ' + myServerName)
      );
    });
```

Comment: I get this error   `TypeError: Cannot read property 'recordset' of undefined.`

Comment: Manage to figure it out.Its Syntax. Thank You very much mate. Cheers